# Get price (amount only, no currency tag, no special characters) from String via RegEx

Tags: regex, vba

I have written a RegEx syntax which also works, but I fear I am missing something or maybe there is a more elegant way too achieve what I need.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/KZxt9I/1

[image]

Goal is to get whatever price there is before the term "EUR":

1. Sometimes the price is written like the first match -> integer (no
   Cents)
2. Sometimes the price is written like the second match ->
   double (with comma due to Cents)

As you can see in the first match there is also ",-" before "EUR" and in the second match the string does not have ",-" before "EUR".

Is my RegEx sufficient enough in case there are more whitespaces inbetween or so?

Comment: If there are any non-whitespace characters inbetween Preis and the first number, it doesn't match. Is this intended? This would exclude numbers written with + or - in-front or numbers starting with ",".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is too complicated, you can make it much simpler:

```
^Preis$\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?).*EUR
^Preis$\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\W*EUR
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y5XI00/1). Note that you only need one capturing group and the rest can be written as consuming patterns as you will extract the contents of Group 1 anyway.

The difference between the two is `\W*` and `.*`, `\W*` matching any zero or more non-word chars while `.*` matching any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The `\s*` you used matches *any zero or more whitespace chars*, so you should not worry about how many whitespace chars there are between `Preis` and the number.

If you need to make sure `EUR` is matched as a whole word, add `\b` right after:

```vb
^Preis$\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\W*EUR\b
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string (or line if `RegEx.Multiline` is *True*)
- `Preis` - a word
- `$` - end of string/line
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digiots and then an optional occurrence of a comma and one or more digits
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars as many as possible
- `EUR\b` - `EUR` as a whole word.

Comment: I knew there is a way more elegant way to achieve this. Thank you! I will def. have a deeper look into your solution. What do you mean by "consuming patterns"? Are those match pattern?

Comment: @smartini You are using several lookaheads in the pattern, `(?=,)` and `(?=.*EUR)`, but you need them only when you need to re-try matching the same text again. That is because lookaheads are non-consuming patterns: the regex index stays where it was before trying the lookahead pattern. Since you are not expecting any other matches in the text matched with `.*EUR`, you can keep it simple, out of any lookaround syntax.

Comment: What should I adjust in the RegEX if the price is written with a thousand separator? E.g. 1.037,- EUR/1000 kg. The RegEx does not catch it as of now. I tried to insert an IF clause like that --> ^Preis$\s*(\d+(?:,(\d+|\d+\.\d+))?)\W*EUR\b

Comment: @smartini You can use `^Preis$\s*(\d+(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)\W*EUR\b`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y5XI00/3).

Comment: wow, thanks for thr prompt reply. It works like a charm. still figuring out why you use {3} after \d... does it have to do with the thousand being separated? why not just use a + instead?

Comment: @smartini In the languages I know the thousand separator only appears every three digits. Use `+` if you need to support some other format.